# MySQLi Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is weird.  I'm only adding one variable to the prepare() and bind_result() and it causes an error.  Here's the code that worked:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT YiD, Title FROM Videos WHERE iD = ?");
$result->bind_param("s",$id);
$result->bind_result($youtubeid, $youtubetitle);
$result->execute();
$result->store_result();
$result->fetch();
```

Now here's the code that didn't work:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT YiD, Title, Desc FROM Videos WHERE iD = ?");
$result->bind_param("s",$id);
$result->bind_result($youtubeid, $youtubetitle, $youtubedesc);
$result->execute();
$result->store_result();
$result->fetch();
```

and it gave me this error - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/content/77/9901377/html/video.php on line 23

Line 23 is the bind_param("s",$id)

I've called the database correctly and everything works in the first code, but when I add some more variables to the code it doesn't work.

Comment: Probably because `DESC` is an SQL keyword and you need to quote it somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desc is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). If you want to use it as a column or table name, you must enclose it in backticks (`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$result` is not an object.

It is an error code or `False`, because you used `Desc` (which is a reserved keyword) here:

```
 $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT YiD, Title, Desc FROM Videos WHERE iD = ?");
```

so that `$mysqli->prepare` returned an error instead of a SQLi object suitable for parameter binding.

Try quoting the column name.